# Is it necessary to run miltiple uWSGI web-sites with different users?

Tags: linux, deployment, nginx, web-deployment, uwsgi

In [the docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#VirtualHosting) they say:

> The customers’ applications can now be run (using the process manager
>   of your choice, such as rc.local, Running uWSGI via Upstart,
>   Supervisord or whatever strikes your fancy) **with a different uid** and a
>   limited (if you want) address space for each socket:

Is it really necessary to do this? If yes - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general security rule. Immagine one of your app being compromised, if it runs with the same permissions of the others it will be potentially able to damage them as well.